# Google Play auto-update of other apps causes YouTube video to pause

Tags: google-play-store, youtube, application-autoupdate

I have set my Google Play to automatically update apps when the phone charging and connected to WiFi. This is convenient to keep apps up-to-date.

The problem is, I may also want to watch new videos from my YouTube subscriptions right after I plugged the phone in to charge. But the auto-update kicks in and after *each* app update is installed, the video in YouTube suddenly pauses. I can tap Play to resume the video, but the video pauses again after the next update is installed.

It doesn't matter what apps are being updated. If there are 15 apps getting updated while I play a long video, the video will pause 15 times!

I should add that there is **no update for YouTube** app itself. The updates are for **other apps** and it doesn't matter which app is updated. Every single update causes a playing YouTube video to pause. **YouTube doesn't quit and it's still on screen, just the video gets paused.**

My device is OnePlus 2 running on latest stock Marshmallow. I'm not sure if this is device specific.

Is there any way to fix this?